# PyQt5: Toggling "Stay on Top" not working in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, linux, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am building a cross-platform application that has a button to toggle a Frameless Window "Stay on top" option using PyQt 5.13.1. I used the following options for achieving this.

`self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.Dialog)` - default window flags

`self.setWindowFlags(window.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)` - disable stay on top,

`self.setWindowFlags(window.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)` - enable stay on top.

These lines work fine in Windows and Mac but don't work in Linux(tried with Ubuntu, CentOS). I've even tried with different window flags but nothing worked out!

Comment: Is this on `X11`?  If so you could try setting the `QtCore.Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint` flag as well to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

[G.M.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58528274/pyqt5-toggling-stay-on-top-not-working-in-ubuntu#comment103380853_58528274) shows a great solution:

just add the `QtCore.Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint` to the window flags.

If you are running the code on a non-linux OS, Python just ignores the flag.

If that was not working, you could add `QtCore.Qt.BypassWindowManagerHint` to the window flags.